# How to use ggplot to show a scale by geom_point?

Tags: r, ggplot2

recently I am using R to draw some maps, and I use the data from `nycflights13::flights` and `nycflights13::airports`

I tried to find out the average delay by destination first

```
library(tidyverse)
library(nycflights13)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

delay1 <- flights %>% 
  group_by(dest) %>% 
  summarise(delay = dep_delay %>% mean(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Then, I joined the average delay by dest to aiports

```
airports2 <- delay1 %>% left_join(airports, c("dest" = "faa"))
```

After that, I tried to point out the average delay by dest in the US map

```
airports2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, col="delay")) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point() +
  coord_quickmap()
```

[image: map]

However, the result turns out that there is only 1 color in delay. But it is supposed that there is a range of delay to be shown in the map.
How I do this?? Thank you very much

Comment: Have you tried with `col=delay` ?

Comment: If you quote "delay", it interprets it as a string rather than a column variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use `fill` option and `shape=21` in order to create a color scale and then modify with `scale_fill_gradient2()`. The great suggestion from **@markus** is also valid. Here another option for you:

```
#Code
airports2 %>%
  ggplot(aes(lon, lat, fill=delay)) +
  borders("state") +
  geom_point(shape=21) +
  coord_quickmap()+
  scale_fill_gradient2(low = 'red',mid = 'purple',high = 'blue')
```

Output:

[image]